# Error Setting WildFly 10 Resource Adapter (wmq.jmsra.rar)

Tags: wildfly, ibm-mq, wildfly-10, jca

**environment:**

Server IBM MQ 9, JVM 8, Wildfly 10

**Error log wildfly:**

```
2017-09-15 10:53:33,955 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (default task-16) IJ000604: Throwable while attempting to get a new connection: null: com.ibm.mq.connector.DetailedResourceException: MQJCA1011: No se ha podido asignar una conexión JMS., error code: MQJCA1011 Un error interno ha hecho que falle un intento de asignar una conexión. Consulte la excepción enlazada para obtener detalles de la anomalía.
    at com.ibm.mq.connector.services.JCAExceptionBuilder.buildException(JCAExceptionBuilder.java:169)   
    at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl$TrackingExecutor$1.run(EndpointImpl.java:731)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSWMQ0018: No se ha podido conectar con el gestor de colas 'MQ.MQAWSHOM.01' con modalidad de conexión 'Client' y nombre de host '172.16.34.210(1414)'.
Compruebe que el gestor de colas esté iniciado y, si se está ejecutando en modalidad de cliente, compruebe que haya un escucha en ejecución. Consulte la excepción enlazada para obtener más información.
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.reasonToException(Reason.java:595)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:215)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.<init>(WMQConnection.java:422)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQXAConnection.<init>(WMQXAConnection.java:67)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQXAConnectionFactory.createV7ProviderConnection(WMQXAConnectionFactory.java:188)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:7814)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQXAConnectionFactory.createProviderXAConnection(WMQXAConnectionFactory.java:98)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.createXAConnectionInternal(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:354)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQXAConnectionFactory.createXAConnection(MQXAConnectionFactory.java:131)
    at com.ibm.mq.connector.ConnectionBuilder.createConnection(ConnectionBuilder.java:134)
    ... 90 more
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: La llamada de IBM MQ ha fallado con código de terminación '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') razón '2058' ('MQRC_Q_MGR_NAME_ERROR').
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:203)
    ... 98 more

2017-09-15 10:53:33,958 INFO  [stdout] (default task-16) MQJCA0002: Se ha producido una excepción en la capa IBM MQ. Consulte la excepción enlazada para obtener detalles.
```

Why am I receiving this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is this:

```
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: La llamada de IBM MQ ha fallado con código de terminación '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') razón '2058' ('MQRC_Q_MGR_NAME_ERROR').
```

This indicates that the queue manager listening at `172.16.34.210(1414)` is not called `MQ.MQAWSHOM.01`.  Check that the IP and port are correct for the queue manager you want to connect to, if those are correct check for any typos in the name of the queue manager you are specifying.

---

If your do not care what queue manager name is listening on the IP and Port specified you can prefix the queue manager name with a `*` character, this will instruct the API to disregard the name of the queue manager.  For example: `*MQ.MQAWSHOM.01`.

Comment: I make a telnet and it works!!!! 
Also from another application I can connect with those same parameters.

I need other libraries besides those contained in the file ra?

Comment: @MIKEL the error is clear, this is not a library problem.  Please double check the queue manager name and the IP and port from your working application are **exactly** the same as what you are specifying here.  If you don't care what queue manager name you connect you you can always prefix it with a `*`, ex: `*MQ.MQAWSHOM.01`.  This would possibly allow you to connect, but may be the wrong queue manager.

Comment: @MIKEL I'm glad that works, but it does then show that the queue manager name listening on the IP and port is NOT `MQ.MQAWSHOM.01`, with out knowing your architecture I would not know if this is a problem.  Please accept the answer by clicking the "grayed out" check mark to the left of the answer under the down arrow, it will turn green indicating it is accepted.